# Wordpress get Image out of Post

Tags: php, wordpress

working on a Wordpress site.
Got some posts and with Image(s).

Trying to get te image from the post within de have_post loop.
(most posts only have's one picture).

I already figured out how to use:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src ( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'thumbnail', bool $icon = false )
```

which should return a array with attributes. array[0] = url.
Now I am not sure how to receive a attachments_id. I know I can get it within the admin panel, but I need to use it within the have_post loop.

Have_post loop:

```
                if (have_posts())
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    if (in_category('Referenties')) {

                        if ($ReferenceAmount % 4) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="references-row">
                                <div class="reference">
                                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id )); ?>

                                    <div class="reference-figure" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Not giving anything. Just started on Wordpress so no hates please. Thanks!

Comment: there is a specific function for this, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: `get_post_thumbnail_id()` is already giving you id of attachment.